# keybd_event on Qt won't work

Tags: qt, lnk2019, qtgui

I'm trying to create some sort of a "virtual controler" on Qt, by sending "keyboard presses" from my apliccation to outside of it (to the system). I tried to use keybd_event, but I'm having problems. Even this simple code won't work:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <windows.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    keybd_event(Qt::Key_Right, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(Qt::Key_Right, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

I get this error message:

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_keybd_event@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@MainWindow@@AAEXXZ)

Can please someone explain why is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) document `keybd_event()` function defined in `User32.dll` library. I think you need to verify whether your application is linked against `User32.lib`.